# Handle exception [invalid.profile.access]. You don't have access to the profile in LinkedIn

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am trying to search the users using LinkedIn API. I got exception

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: [invalid.profile.access]. You don't have access to the profile
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.createLinkedInApiClientException(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3906)
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3781)
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3725)
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.getProfileById(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:1067)
```

How Would i handle this exception. I want to see only the users profile of the user who has visible their profile to public.
I am using linkedin-j library using java

```
LinkedInApiClient liClient;
    Map<SearchParameter,String> searchParameters =new EnumMap<SearchParameter, String>(SearchParameter.class);
    searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.FIRST_NAME, firstName);
    searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.LAST_NAME, lastName);
    people =liClient.searchPeople(searchParameters,start,25);
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @JunedAhsan. I added my code. please check